# SparkR save ML model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, sparkr

How to save a SparkR model and load the model separately and predict?
Spark version 2.0

```
# Load training data
 df <- read.df("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt", source = "libsvm")
 training <- df
 testing <- df

# Fit a random forest classification model with spark.randomForest
 model <- spark.randomForest(training, label ~ features, "classification", numTrees = 10)

# Model summary
 summary(model)



 ### Save and Load
 ??

# Prediction
 predictions <- predict(model, test)
 head(predictions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [**`read.ml(path)`**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.ml.html) and [**`write.ml(object, path)`**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/write.ml.html)

Comment: You were faster than me :-)

Comment: Ha :) I don't even use SparkR

Comment: Me neither but I'm looking for the gold medal in Spark :)

Comment: I'm a long way off that target